# How can I stop new Command Prompt windows spawned by another program from covering my foreground window?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, 64-bit, window-manager, exact-audio-copy

Under Windows 7 x64, when I'm ripping CDs with [Exact Audio Copy](http://www.exactaudiocopy.de/), it spawns a Command Prompt window each time it invokes the external MP3 compression program I use, [LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/).

While that's going on, I usually like to surf the web.  However, I find it quite annoying that even when Firefox has the foreground, the Command Prompt windows spawned by EAC are coming up in the *foreground*, on top of my Firefox window.

Is there a way to make those new Command Prompt windows spawn in the background?  Alternatively, is there a way to make the current active window stay in the foreground / on top while I'm using it?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you ask the EAC author to add a feature to launch external programs minimized.

In the mean time, you could run EAC on another [Desktop](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx) or make the Firefox window [topmost](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195516) with something like [Deskpins](http://users.forthnet.gr/pat/efotinis/programs/deskpins.html).